# Are cut cards reshuffled in blackjack?

Tags: blackjack

In blackjack, card deck is reshuffled once there are less than 60 to 75 undrawn cards left in the deck. Are these cards included in next shuffle session and then cut again, or are these particular cards thrown away for all deals in the session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a shoe is shuffled (or reshuffled), all cards are shuffled, then the cut card is placed near the back of the shoe.  This card is only an indicator that the shoe needs to be reshuffled at the end of the current hand.  Thus, cards behind the cut card can and will be played into the hand.  The purpose of the cut card's placement is two-fold: first, it's to ensure that enough cards exist so the hand can be played out even under the worst conditions (e.g. 6 players splitting and drawing 5 could, theoretically require 60 cards).  Second, it's to discourage card counting as any form of keeping track of the cards seen increases one's odds as the shoe runs down.  Not using the last part of the shoe, thus, eliminates the worst of the counting problem, though it doesn't eliminate it entirely.